# Why can't the compiler detect the minus sign in my code?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am facing problems with the compiler. My code snippet is below , but when I run it , it compiles differently and can't detect the
'-' (minus) sign and replaces it with '?' (question mark) , making it to be a ternary operator.

***My code*** :-

```
unsigned long long int find(long int N , int K){
   if(K == 2){
      return 2*(N - 1)*(N - 1);
   }

   else{
      return(find(N − 1 , K) + find(N − 1 , K − 1) + find(N − 2 , K − 1));
   }
}
```

***Compiler error :-***

```
prog.c: In function ‘find’:
prog.c:52:27: warning: left-hand operand of comma expression has no effect [-Wunused-value]
     return(find(N ? 1 , K) + find(N ? 1 , K ? 1) + find(N ? 2 , K ? 1));
                       ^
prog.c:52:30: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘)’ token
     return(find(N ? 1 , K) + find(N ? 1 , K ? 1) + find(N ? 2 , K ? 1));
                          ^
prog.c:52:16: error: too few arguments to function ‘find’
     return(find(N ? 1 , K) + find(N ? 1 , K ? 1) + find(N ? 2 , K ? 1));
```

I have tried using C-compiler of codechef and geeksforgeeks, but still it gives the compilation error.
Please suggest what should be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some places your code actually contains [U+2212](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2212/index.htm) Unicode Minus Sign.

Typically compilers will not accept this, you should use the ASCII minus sign.

I would recommend using a text editor that does not allow entry of non-ascii characters, that would avoid this sort of problem.

Comment: @KaustavBhattacharjee Perhaps you have some input mode on your computer that converts ascii minus to unicode minus, who knows ... maybe you could install a programmer editor such as vim or Notepad++ and copy-paste your code into codechef if that's what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks a lot M.M , now the above code is working but I still don't know how. I just searched ASCII minus sign on google and copied it and just pressed minus in my keyboard and the compiler is detecting it (codechef compiler)